# OSX font width different the windows for standard cross platform fonts

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a css menu on a webpage that is flowed horizontaly, as the items text in the menu are different widths I have used a padded amount around the text so that the entire menu takes up close to 100% of my page width. The structure is something like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"> item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#"> item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#"> item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

This looks fine in windows under a variety of browsers include Safari on windows. But on OSX safari / firefox the same emnu ahs an element pushed to the next line - breaking the menu. It seem that a 12px high Arial font is rendered a little wider on OSX the windows.

Is this right? I thought that the font reffered to as a cross platform font would be rendered the same. Is this perhaps poor practice [I'm adding padding the the a element to increase the target size for clicking on]

[image: Not to scale screen shots showing mac below windows above]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font rendering differs from one OS to another, and there's not much we can do about it.

If you strictly need that menu to be as wide as the entire page, I see two solutions:

- Assign the same width to every menu item (and make sure that the text contents fit)
- Use `display: table` on the `<ul>` container and `display: table-cell` on each menu item.

Here's an example of the second strategy: http://jsfiddle.net/MartinodF/J8GX3/

Note that `display: table` is [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=table) by IE7.

Comment: Note that display: table is not supported by IE7.
- thats a killer for me as I am aiming for IE6 compatibility if possible.

Comment: Well, IE6-7 are just going to ignore the `display: table`, so you could always make them fall back to your current strategy (which, I understand, works well in every browser on Windows). If you need, you can use conditional comments to target those two browsers.